# How assign differing attributes to multiple elements of the same class based on text value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, attributes, selector

So for example:

I have multiple `<span>` elements with the class of `.listing-text` that say `Available`, some that say `Pending`, and some that say `Sold`.

I'd like to assign a `green` background to the ones that say `Available`, `yellow` to `Pending`, and `red` to `Sold`.

I've tried a few different for loops and whatnot. All I've been able to make work so far is just turning every box green, and I assume that's because I'm not iterating properly. The only thing I can seem to get right is

```
$('.listing-text').css('background-color','green');
```

It reliably changes all backgrounds to green.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the entire HTML chunk for the element of `.listing-text`?

Comment: Can you apply classes of "available", "pending", and "sold" to your spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```js
// Get all the listings and loop over them
document.querySelectorAll(".listing-text").forEach(function(listing){
  // Check the text of the span for the possible choices and
  // apply the appropriate CSS class
  switch (listing.textContent) {
    case "Available":
      listing.classList.add("available");
      break;
    case "Pending":
      listing.classList.add("pending");
      break;
    case "Sold":
      listing.classList.add("sold");
      break;       
  }
});
```

```css
.available { background-color:green; }
.pending { background-color:yellow; }
.sold { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<span class="listing-text">Available</span>
<span class="listing-text">Pending</span>
<span class="listing-text">Sold</span>
<span class="listing-text">Available</span>
<span class="listing-text">Pending</span>
<span class="listing-text">Sold</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't write a css selector that matches on the text of the element (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520469/8755370).

You could instead loop over the whole set of listings and add another class for each category. So all would have `.listing-text` but some would be `.listing-available` or `.listing-pending`. From there you can write your jquery functions like the one you posted.

Comment: This is what ended up working. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using jQuery's [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```js
$('.listing-text').each(function() {
    let listText = $(this).text()
    switch (listText) {
        case 'Pending':
            $(this).addClass('pending')
            break
        case 'Sold':
            $(this).addClass('sold')
            break
        case 'Available':
        default:
            $(this).addClass('available')
            break
    }
})
```

```css
.available {  background-color: green  }
.pending {  background-color: yellow  }
.sold {  background-color: red  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="listing-text">Available</span>
<span class="listing-text">Sold</span>
<span class="listing-text">Pending</span>
```

What I've done here is loop over each listing-text element, get the text, and apply a class based on its text value.

Comment: Wow, awesome solution. Different direction than I was thinking in, but completely solved my problem. Thanks for taking the time to help, Andrew.